# Объединение двух csv файлов

Tags: python, pandas

Есть два csv файла, по отдельности всё отображается нормально, но когда объединяю их то часть информации из второго меняется на NaN. Надо сделать всё через Pandas.
Пробовал так

```
data_dir = Path("csv/")
df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in data_dir.glob("*.csv")], ignore_index=True)
df.to_csv("result.csv", index=False)
```

И так

```
df2 = pd.read_csv('csv/commits.csv')
df3 = pd.read_csv('csv/issues.csv')
df4 = pd.concat([df2, df3])
```

Вот ссылка на файлы
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1WeeyV2WT83T0-7D5Qy9pF85HemMrDKoe?usp=sharing

Comment: Вы не торОпитесь? потому что мы долго будем выяснять содержимое ваших файлов телепатическим путём.

Comment: @strawdog добавил ссылку на файлы

Comment: ну так у вас фреймы с разной структурой. по умолчанию concat соединяет  по колонкам, дописывая индекс второго фрейма к первому. а у вас колонки не совпадают. почитайте про pandas.join() или более универсальный pandas.merge(), если хотите объединять файлы по индексу

Comment: у вас вообще ни один индекс по обеим осям не совпадает в обоих файлах. как именно вы хотите их объединить-то?

Comment: @strawdog у меня есть задача в которой мне просто сказано объединить два этих файла, я подумал что через concat будет нормально, но я ошибся.